# merge multiple dynamic streams into one

Tags: c, gstreamer

I have the following pipeline:

```
 appsrc->h264parse->av264_dec->videoconvert->x264enc->appsink
```

I am feeding h264 stream into the appsrc (together with timestamps) and getting h264 stream out of appsink (also with timestamps). This works for me.

However, I would like to have a pipeline with two inputs (appsrc...) and only one output (appsink). The idea is that all inputs are constantly being fed with data and decoded, but only one of them is selected for output (others are discarded).

For simplicity we can assume that one stream is a background stream (generated eg. by videotestsrc) and is available at all times. Other streams can appear/disappear at various times, for simplicity we can assume that a stream appears only once (another appearance is a new stream).

Now the question is how do I organize switching between those streams? Should I unlink the GstElements and link them another way? Or should I use `input-selector`? Then what does the `input-selector` do with streams from inactive pads? Does it discard them or does it put them on hold and consume when pad is active again?

I also seem to have an issue with understanding timestamps. The stream fed into each appsrc has separate set of timestamps. For simplicity we can assume that each timestamp starts from 0. However, as those streams start at different points in wall time, 0 from one stream does not mean the same time as 0 from another stream. Therefore the question is how they should be synchronized? Should this somehow be done manually when injecting the data into each appsrc (calculate offsets) or does GStreamer provide any mechanism to address this problem, possibly later in the pipeline?

Comment: _Input selector_...  Is there some unique byte string that can be used to distinguish one stream from the other?  i.e. I assume some part of each packet includes a header section.

Comment: In the application I can distinguish them and I have means to direct each one to separate appsrc instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the `compositor` element may be helpful to you. You can arrange/compose different streams here. I guess you can put one stream above each other and then toggle their appearance with the `zorder` property of the input pads.

Comment: It worked with the `compositor` element - not sure it wouldn't with `input-selector` though, maybe will check one day. On the way to get it working I had an issue that the 'background' stream was played, then the 'foreground' stream started and played and then everything stopped - no `zorder` changes helped to get back to 'background' stream and last frame of the 'foreground' stream stayed on screen. The issue was that I didn't indicate to `appsrc` that the stream was ended with `end-of-stream` signal which caused the whole pipeline to hang. Adding that everything works fine.

Comment: And btw, I am calculating timestamps myself based on system time and it works reasonably well - there is some stream switching delay but it might be caused by h264 encoding.